# google map is rendered with multiple rounded tiles

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, matrix, google-api

[map is devided into 3x3 tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rac0a.png)

I want to remove all the spaces and rounded corners so the map looks as if it is one full map without any divisions into tiles, maybe there is some kind of map tile atribute that I can modify to make it look like a normal map, below is my code

```html
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    });
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  // get route from A to B
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      swal("не удалось загрузить карту");
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

Comment: That is a. CSS issue (your CSS is being applied to the map `<img>` tiles when it shouldn't be).  You didn't post any CSS.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: that is the answer I was looking for thank you)))

Answer (score 0):

the tiles of the map are effected by img styling, I changed my css to bypass the map styling and it solved my issue